# Attach a property in context(request in express.js) object

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, prisma, express-graphql

I'm new to **GraphQL**, and I'm now trying to make an API server with `express-graphql`.

What I want to do is add new property in `context` object for resolvers, which can be done when I initialize the `express-graphql` server instance.

According to the official document, it saids by default, if nothing is specified in the code, the `context` object in every resolver function will have an object which was *previously called `req` in **Express.js***.

```js
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
)
// by this,
// in resolver there will be `context` available
// which includes the data previously available in `req` object (express.js case)
```

Then, what should I do if I want to add my own custom property in the `req` or `context` object, with all `req`'s members altogether? I just want to add one or two new values, but not to lose other values `req` already has.

```js
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: {
      customData: 'Yay!'
    }
  })
)
// I was able to add my own data in `context`,
// but eventually I lost all of data which was previously in the `req` object!
```

Any good idea or knowledge will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this like that

```
app.use('/graphql', expressGraphql(req => ({
  schema,
  graphiql: false,
  context: {
    ...req,
    customData: 'Yay!'
  }
})))
```

Refer the doc https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#providing-extensions

Comment: This seems a simple and authentic way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a middleware to add, use it before configuring graphqlHTTP.

```
const setMyContext = (myContext = {}) => {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        req.myContext = myContext;
        next()
    }
};

app.use(setMyContext({
    customData: 'Yay!'
}));

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
)
```

U can access customData by

**req.myContext.customData**

Comment: This is a way of adding data indirectly. This should also work. Thanks.